# how to find the hello.c file path?

Tags: linux, centos

[image]

i wrote a `hello world` example.and run successfully,but i don't know where it is in the linux sys. When I run the command `which hello.c`. it doesn't show the path of the hello.c file . how to find out where's the path of the  `hello.c` file. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely in the current directory.  Try `ls -l hello.c`.

Also, don't compile or debug software as root unless you have to.  A bug in your code could completely hose your system.

Comment: +1, especially if you're using `./` before the command

Answer (score 2):

`which` shows you the location of executables; hello.c is a source file.  If you wrote it, ideally you should remember where you put it.  If not, something like

```
find ~ -name hello.c
```

might be useful (if it's somewhere under your home directory).

But first, try

```
ls -l hello.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `find / -type f -name 'hello.c'` as root.  Depending on how big and how stuffed your hard drive is, it will take some time.